# JSTL EL not Working in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I wrote a web application with Eclipse Tomcat and it works on my local Tomcat 7, when I tried to publish it online on a Tomcat 7, I am getting value of EL in JSTL tag value as null. I have included jstl-1.1.2.jar and standard.jar inside /WEB-INF/lib on the production server. Directive for including jstl is standard:

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Also I have declared the specs in web.xml as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Also I am not getting any kind of exception/error in this.

Below is code snippet for the same

```
 <c:if test='${not empty UserProfileInfo}'>
<p>Hello</p>    

 </c:if>
```

Every time UserProfileInfo is getting as null. This is problem is only happening in case of production server as on my local machine it is working fine.

Comment: Are you saying that an expression like `${someVar}` shows up as `null` in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Hi Sotirios Delimanolis---- I am getting the value null  of expression like ${someVar} every time. For Ex. <c:if test='${not empty UserProfileInfo}'>
  <nav class="nav center">
   <ul>
             <li  class="current"> <a href="<bean:message key="link.path.indexpage.rechargehistory"/>">My Recharges</a></li>               
               <li><a href="<bean:message key="link.path.indexpage.userprofile"/>">My Profile</a></li>
              

   </ul>
  </nav>
    </c:if>

Comment: Hi Aniket--- Please Refer below code <c:if test='${not empty UserProfileInfo}'>
<p>Hello</p>    

 </c:if>

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues. You can refer to the solution that I found for this problem at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25374024/1443527